# Error: useTheme: `theme` is undefined. Seems you forgot to wrap your app in `<NativeBaseProvider />`

Tags: react-native, npm, expo

> Error: useTheme: `theme` is undefined. Seems you forgot to wrap your
> app in `<NativeBaseProvider />`
>
> This error is located at:
> in ForwardRef(Container)
> in ForwardRef(Container) (at ProductContainer.js:166)
> in ProductContainer (at SceneView.tsx:122)
> in StaticContainer
> in StaticContainer (at SceneView.tsx:115)
> in EnsureSingleNavigator (at SceneView.tsx:114)
> in SceneView (at useDescriptors.tsx:153)
> in RCTView (at View.js:34)
> in View (at CardContainer.tsx:245)
> in RCTView (at View.js:34)
> in View (at CardContainer.tsx:244)
> in RCTView (at View.js:34)
> in View (at CardSheet.tsx:33)
> in ForwardRef(CardSheet) (at Card.tsx:573)
> in RCTView (at View.js:34)
> in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:165)
> in AnimatedComponent (at createAnimatedComponent.js:215)
> in ForwardRef(AnimatedComponentWrapper) (at Card.tsx:555)
> in PanGestureHandler (at GestureHandlerNative.tsx:13)
> in PanGestureHandler (at Card.tsx:549)
> in RCTView (at View.js:34)
> in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:165)
> in AnimatedComponent (at createAnimatedComponent.js:215)
> in ForwardRef(AnimatedComponentWrapper) (at Card.tsx:544)
> in RCTView (at View.js:34)
> in View (at Card.tsx:538)
> in Card (at CardContainer.tsx:206)
> in CardContainer (at CardStack.tsx:623)
> in RNSScreen (at createAnimatedComponent.js:165)
> in AnimatedComponent (at createAnimatedComponent.js:215)
> in ForwardRef(AnimatedComponentWrapper) (at src/index.native.tsx:120)
> in Screen (at Screens.tsx:74)
> in MaybeScreen (at CardStack.tsx:616)
> in RNSScreenContainer (at src/index.native.tsx:145)
> in ScreenContainer (at Screens.tsx:50)
> in MaybeScreenContainer (at CardStack.tsx:498)
> in CardStack (at StackView.tsx:462)
> in KeyboardManager (at StackView.tsx:458)
> in SafeAreaProviderCompat (at StackView.tsx:455)
> in GestureHandlerRootView (at GestureHandlerRootView.android.tsx:26)
> in GestureHandlerRootView (at StackView.tsx:454)
> in StackView (at createStackNavigator.tsx:87)
> in StackNavigator (at HomeNavigator.js:11)
> in MyStack (at HomeNavigator.js:31)
> in HomeNavigator (at SceneView.tsx:122)
> in StaticContainer
> in StaticContainer (at SceneView.tsx:115)
> in EnsureSingleNavigator (at SceneView.tsx:114)
> in SceneView (at useDescriptors.tsx:153)
> in RCTView (at View.js:34)
> in View (at BottomTabView.tsx:55)
> in SceneContent (at BottomTabView.tsx:172)
> in RNSScreen (at createAnimatedComponent.js:165)
> in AnimatedComponent (at createAnimatedComponent.js:215)
> in ForwardRef(AnimatedComponentWrapper) (at src/index.native.tsx:120)
> in Screen (at ResourceSavingScene.tsx:30)
> in ResourceSavingScene (at BottomTabView.tsx:166)
> in RNSScreenContainer (at src/index.native.tsx:145)
> in ScreenContainer (at BottomTabView.tsx:146)
> in RNCSafeAreaProvider (at SafeAreaContext.tsx:76)
> in SafeAreaProvider (at SafeAreaProviderCompat.tsx:42)
> in SafeAreaProviderCompat (at BottomTabView.tsx:145)
> in BottomTabView (at createBottomTabNavigator.tsx:45)
> in BottomTabNavigator (at Main.js:21)
> in Main (at App.js:28)
> in EnsureSingleNavigator (at BaseNavigationContainer.tsx:409)
> in ForwardRef(BaseNavigationContainer) (at NavigationContainer.tsx:91)
> in ThemeProvider (at NavigationContainer.tsx:90)
> in ForwardRef(NavigationContainer) (at App.js:26)
> in Provider (at App.js:25)
> in Auth (at App.js:24)
> in App (created by ExpoRoot)
> in ExpoRoot (at renderApplication.js:45)
> in RCTView (at View.js:34)
> in View (at AppContainer.js:106)
> in RCTView (at View.js:34)
> in View (at AppContainer.js:132)
> in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:39) at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:104:6 in
> reportException at
> node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:171:19
> in handleException at
> node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/setUpErrorHandling.js:24:6 in
> handleError at
> node_modules/expo-error-recovery/build/ErrorRecovery.fx.js:12:21 in
> ErrorUtils.setGlobalHandler$argument_0 at [native code]:null in
> flushedQueue at [native code]:null in
> invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue Error: ENOENT: no such file or
> directory, watch '/home/user/sj/front/node_modules/nan/doc'
> at FSWatcher. (internal/fs/watchers.js:218:26)
> at Object.watch (fs.js:1582:34)
> at NodeWatcher.watchdir (/home/user/sj/front/node_modules/sane/src/node_watcher.js:159:22)
> at NodeWatcher. (/home/user/sj/front/node_modules/sane/src/node_watcher.js:295:18)
> at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:193:5)

https://github.com/SHARUNJOSEPH/front-server

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn about the rules of the site as well as [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question.

Answer (score 3):

Try downgrading native-base to 2.15.2, works for me. you might need to use npm install native-base@2.15.2 --force

Answer (score 3):

After a hole day of struggle i found a solution to test it with jest.
I had to add a wrapper.

You can wrap it directly with NativeBaseProvider, dont forget the prop `initialWindowMetrics`

Example:

```
const wrapper = ({children}: any) => (
  <NativeBaseProvider
    initialWindowMetrics={{
      frame: {x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0},
      insets: {top: 0, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0},
    }}>
    {children}
  </NativeBaseProvider>
);
 test('renders with App', () => {
    const homeScreen = render(
      <HomeScreen/>,
      {wrapper},
    ).toJSON();
    expect(homeScreen).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

After investing my 2 days. I got the solution to downgrade the native base. Just run this line.

npm install native-base@2.15.2 --force

Answer (score 0):

```js
import { NativeBaseProvider } from 'native-base';

export default function App() {
    return (
        <NativeBaseProvider>
            <Auth>
                <Provider store={store}>
                    <NavigationContainer>
                        <Header />
                        <Main />
                        <Toast ref={(ref) => Toast.setRef(ref)} />
                    </NavigationContainer>
                </Provider>
            </Auth>
        </NativeBaseProvider>
    );
}
```

Comment: I have the same issue but in Jest tests, so your comment does not really help. Also the question is not fairly understandable ...

Answer (score 0):

No need to downgrade. I'm using the latest version of Nativebase 3.2.1. Just you need to create the NavigationContainer as a separate component.

```js
    import React from 'react';
    import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
    import { NativeBaseProvider, useColorModeValue, useToken } from 'native-base';
    import RootStackNavigator from './RootStackNavigator'; // Change your root navigator
    
    const MyNavigationContainer = () => {
      const [lightBg, darkBg] = useToken(
        'colors',
        ['coolGray.50', 'blueGray.900'],
        'blueGray.900',
      );
      const bgColor = useColorModeValue(lightBg, darkBg);
      return (
        <NavigationContainer
          theme={{
            colors: { background: bgColor },
          }}>
            <RootStackNavigator />
        </NavigationContainer>
      );
    };
    
    const App = () => {
      return (
        <NativeBaseProvider>
          <MyNavigationContainer />
        </NativeBaseProvider>
      );
    };
    
    export default App;
```